# Label row when value changes pandas

Tags: python, pandas, label

I need a solution for the following problem. What I have is a timestamp and a value. This value can change positive, negative or remains steady. As soon as it changes positively from one row to another or stays steady, I want to add a label in a new column. If the value continues to increase, the same label should be added to the row. As soon as the value changes negatively, a zero should be entered as label. Can anyone help me?

Input Data

```
df_raw = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "timestamp": [
            "2017-06-16 05:19:18.993",
            "2017-06-16 05:19:28.993",
            "2017-06-16 05:19:38.993",
            "2017-06-16 05:19:48.993",
            "2017-06-16 05:19:58.993",
            "2017-06-16 05:25:08.993",
            "2017-06-16 05:25:18.993",
            "2017-06-16 07:44:28.993",
            "2017-06-16 07:45:38.993",
        ],
        "signalvalue": [0.0, 12.0, 22.0, 13.0, 0.0, 30.0, 0.0, 3.0, 6.0],
    }
)

    timestamp                signalvalue
0   2017-06-16 05:19:18.993  0.0
1   2017-06-16 05:19:28.993  12.0
2   2017-06-16 05:19:38.993  22.0
3   2017-06-16 05:19:48.993  13.0
4   2017-06-16 05:19:58.993  0.0
5   2017-06-16 05:25:08.993  30.0
6   2017-06-16 05:25:18.993  0.0
7   2017-06-16 07:44:28.993  3.0
8   2017-06-16 07:45:38.993  6.0
```

Desired Output

```
    timestamp                signalvalue    label
0   2017-06-16 05:19:18.993  0.0            0
1   2017-06-16 05:19:28.993  12.0           1
2   2017-06-16 05:19:38.993  22.0           1
3   2017-06-16 05:19:48.993  13.0           0
4   2017-06-16 05:19:58.993  0.0            0
5   2017-06-16 05:25:08.993  30.0           2
6   2017-06-16 05:25:18.993  0.0            0
7   2017-06-16 07:44:28.993  3.0            3
8   2017-06-16 07:45:38.993  6.0            3
```

Comment: To clarify: The `label` value should increment each time a new occurrence is seen? And what have you tried, what went wrong with your attempts? We ask that questions include a [mcve] showing code for what you've tried so far

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compute a mask based on the `diff` of the successive values, if greater than zero. Then keep only the first item of each stretch to compute a `cumsum`:

```
m1= df_raw['signalvalue'].diff().gt(0)

df_raw['label'] = (m1&m1.ne(m1.shift())).cumsum()*m1.astype(int)
```

Output:

```
                 timestamp  signalvalue  label
0  2017-06-16 05:19:18.993          0.0      0
1  2017-06-16 05:19:28.993         12.0      1
2  2017-06-16 05:19:38.993         22.0      1
3  2017-06-16 05:19:48.993         13.0      0
4  2017-06-16 05:19:58.993          0.0      0
5  2017-06-16 05:25:08.993         30.0      2
6  2017-06-16 05:25:18.993          0.0      0
7  2017-06-16 07:44:28.993          3.0      3
8  2017-06-16 07:45:38.993          6.0      3
```

Comment: This works fineso far! But I recognized a mistake by myself. The Label should not be zero if the difference between the values stays steady. So only if the difference is negative the Label should be 0. Otherwise it should increase like discribed. How can I add this into your solution? Thanks !

Comment: I guess replace `gt(0)` (greater than) with `ge(0)` (greater or equal)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the following function:

```
def increment_method_1(df,name):
    Results=[]
    last_result=0
    prev_val=0
    for val in df[name].values:
        if val==0 or (val>0 and prev_val>=val):
            Results.append(0)
        elif prev_val<val and prev_val!=0:
            Results.append(last_result)
        elif prev_val<val and prev_val==0:
            last_result+=1
            Results.append(last_result)
        else:
            print(prev_val,val,last_result)
            print("Unexpected condition")
        prev_val=val
    return Results
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are expecting the output like the following code snippet.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_raw = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "timestamp": [
            "2017-06-16 05:19:18.993",
            "2017-06-16 05:19:28.993",
            "2017-06-16 05:19:38.993",
            "2017-06-16 05:19:48.993",
            "2017-06-16 05:19:58.993",
            "2017-06-16 05:25:08.993",
            "2017-06-16 05:25:18.993",
            "2017-06-16 07:44:28.993",
            "2017-06-16 07:45:38.993",
        ],
        "signalvalue": [0.0, 12.0, 22.0, 13.0, 0.0, 30.0, 0.0, 3.0, 6.0],
    }
)

modified = np.zeros((len(df_raw),)).astype(int)
positive = 0 

for i in range(1, len(df_raw)):
    if df_raw["signalvalue"][i] > df_raw["signalvalue"][i - 1]:
        if modified[i - 1] == 0:
            positive += 1
            modified[i] = positive
        else:
            modified[i] = positive

    
df_raw['label'] = modified
```